# Running python directly in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

Is it possible to execute short python expressions in one line in terminal, without passing a file?

e.g. (borrowing from how I would write an awk expression)

`python 'print("hello world")'`

Comment: yes, just type python -i or python in terminal and then just type print("hello world"). I think you need to undestand some basics first before you proceed further : )

Comment: @naivepredictor I didn't want an interactive interpreter I wanted to run a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python3 -c "print('Hello')"`

Use the -c flag as above.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Python3.6

```
    python -c "print('hello world')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run in terminal:

```
$ python

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.randint(0,10,2)
>>> [8,4]
>>> exit()
```

This way you can run a notebook in terminal.

You can also use `argparse` to add conditions/inputs to your python command line, in a previous notebook, `integer.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('--size', dest='size', type=int, default=10, help='number of integers')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
print(np.random.randint(0,10,args['size']))

$ python integer.py --size=3
$ [0,2,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I found you can also feed a here-string to python.

`python <<< 'print("hello world")'`